# Maximum allowable number of lists in various versions of SP

Tags: list, custom-list

Could you please share the maximum allowable number of lists (upper limit of list) in different versions of Sharepoint?

Comment: Dear Robert,

Glad connecting with you.I see great possibility of connecting with you on Linkedin.As I have exceeded all my sending invitation limits,may I request you to send me an invitation to connect.
I am there as Jay Anand Singh,Software Engineer at TCS.
Great to acknowledge you as an integral member on this forum.
Thanking you in anticipation.
Regards,
Jay Bhubaneswar,Orissa INDIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , it's not mentioned at official MSDN Software boundaries and limits, but it's suggested to don't be more than `2000 lists per website`. Check [Plan for software boundaries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx)

Check also [Comparing List and Library limits in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint 2013 / 2010 / 2007](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/05/compare-sharepoint-2016-list-library-limits-with-sharepoint-2013-2010/)

Comment: Dear @JayAnandSingh Should you set it as answer If it's useful and helped you :) thanks for appreciating my time :)

Comment: I have done the desired. Which company do you work for? And which location are you based out of? Great if we can connect on Linkedin. As I have exceeded all my sending invitation limits,may I request you to please send me an invitation on Linked. I am there as Jay Anand Singh,Software Engineer at TCS.Happy Linking and great to have you on this forum.Regards & Best Wishes,

Comment: Dear Qassas, Hope you have sent me an invitation to connect on Linkedin. Also requesting you to share your gmail id.Mine is jayanands.08@gmail.com.Shall connect with you in case required. Anyways Happy Linking...Regards,Jay Bhubaneswar Orissa,INDIA